# How to overwrite bourbon neat Omega()

Tags: html, css, bourbon, neat

I'm currently working on a layout that requires a different layout on mobile, tablet and desktop.

1. **Mobile**  - Stacked
2. **Tablet**  - two column layout
3. **desktop** - three column

I'm finding that my two columns layout sticks all the way up to my desktop layout which shouldn't be the case. It seems that the tablet `omega(2n)`sticks all the way up to my desktop layout... where it should be `omega(3n)` – I thought it would override the Omega(2n). How do I resolve this? I could edit my breakpoints to include max value but it becomes more leg work from there which I think is unnecessary. Here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/NrqBjv)

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxes">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$mq-s :  em(400);
$mq-m :  em(768);
$mq-l :  em(960);
$mq-xl:  em(1700);

// Breakpoints
$mobile:            new-breakpoint(min-width $mq-s 6);
$tablet:            new-breakpoint(min-width $mq-m 12);
$desktop:           new-breakpoint(min-width $mq-l 12);
$large-desktop:     new-breakpoint(min-width $mq-xl 12);

.boxes{
  @include outer-container;
}

@include media ($tablet){
  li {
    background: tint(red,50%);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    @include span-columns(6);
    @include omega(2n);
    height: 40px;
  }
}

@include media ($desktop){
  li{
      @include span-columns(4);
      @include omega(3n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your $tablet media query doesn't have a max-width so it can still conflict with the $desktop media query. Add a max-width like this and it works as you want.

```
$tablet:    new-breakpoint(min-width $mq-m max-width 959px 12);
```

I find it easier to organise my media queries within elements like this

```
li {
  background: tint(red,50%);
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;    

  @include media($tablet){
    @include span-columns(6);
    @include omega(2n);
  }

  @include media($desktop){
    @include span-columns(4);
    @include omega(3n);    
  }
}
```

Now your colours, heights and bottom margins are shared across screen sizes but the columns respond to media queries. No media query necessary for mobile as it becomes default.

Comment: I'd have way too many media queries no? It would make finding elements a bore too.